# removing a sublist if a string in the sublist contains a substring (all values within all sublists are strings)

Tags: python, list, substring, list-comprehension, nested-lists

Given nested list: `mistake_list = [['as','as*s','sd','*ssa'],['a','ds','dfg','mal']]`

Required output: `corrected_list = [['a','ds','dfg','mal']]`

Now the given list can contain hundreds or thousands of sublists in which the strings may or may not contain the special character `*`, but if it does that whole sublist has to be removed.

I have shown an example above where the `mistake_list` is the input nested list, and `corrected_list` is the output nested list.

NOTE: all sublists have an equal number of elements (I don't think it is necessary to know this though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`filter`](https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-filter-list/) function can help you:

```
mistake_list = [['as','as*s','sd','*ssa'],['a','ds','dfg','mal']]
corrected_list = list(filter(lambda l: not any("*" in x for x in l), mistake_list))

print(corrected_list)
```

```
[['a', 'ds', 'dfg', 'mal']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension:

```py
mistake_list = [['as','as*s','sd','*ssa'],['a','ds','dfg','mal']]

corrected_list = [sublst for sublst in mistake_list if not any('*' in s for s in sublst)]
print(corrected_list) # [['a', 'ds', 'dfg', 'mal']]
```

The filtering condition here checks whether there is any `'*'` character in each item of `sublst`.